# Custom ScriptUI buttons that will close the window

Tags: javascript, button, window, extendscript, adobe-scriptui

For those knowledgeable in ExtendScript & InDesign, I have a ScriptUI question:  How can I have a window close properly after the user picks one button or the other *when the buttons are custom choices*.  See the code below:

```
$.writeln("The user pressed " + chooseOyo("123456"));

function chooseOyo(jobNumber) {
    var machine;
    var getOyoWindow = new Window ("dialog", "Which Imagesetter?");
        var textGroup = getOyoWindow.add("group");
            textGroup.orientation = "column";
            textGroup.add("statictext", undefined, "The current job is " + jobNumber);
            textGroup.add("statictext", undefined, "Please choose an imagesetter for this job:");
        var buttonGroup = getOyoWindow.add("group");
            var o1 = buttonGroup.add("button", undefined, "OYO 1");
            var o2 = buttonGroup.add("button", undefined, "OYO 2");
                o1.onClick = function () {machine = "OYO1";}
                o2.onClick = function () {machine = "OYO2";}

    if (getOyoWindow.show() == 1) {
        return machine;
    } else {
        exit();
    }
}
```

Fairly simple, no?  Well, so far, the buttons don't do anything and you have to hit [ESC] in order to cancel the window.  How can I get this to work?

Comment: Did you try getOyoWindow.close() instead of exit?

Comment: Just tried it&mdash;no go.  The window stays persistent no matter which button is pressed.  Only a press of [ESC] gets rid of it and leaves the result of the function "undefined".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: got the right answer:

```
$.writeln("The user pressed " + chooseOyo("123456"));
function chooseOyo(jobNumber) {
    var machine;
    var getOyoWindow = new Window ("dialog", "Which Imagesetter?");
        var textGroup = getOyoWindow.add("group");
            textGroup.orientation = "column";
            textGroup.add("statictext", undefined, "The current job is " + jobNumber);
            textGroup.add("statictext", undefined, "Please choose an imagesetter for this job:");
        var buttonGroup = getOyoWindow.add("group");
            var o1 = buttonGroup.add("button", undefined, "OYO 1");
            var o2 = buttonGroup.add("button", undefined, "OYO 2");
                o1.onClick = function () {
                    machine = "OYO1";

                    getOyoWindow.close(); // thats the trick!

                    }
                o2.onClick = function () {
                    machine = "OYO2";
                    }
    if (getOyoWindow.show() == 1) {
    return machine;

    } else {
    return;
    }
}
```

close() was right. But not using it within the if(win.show() == 1)else{} block. Instead use it within the onClick function of one of the buttons.

Answer (score 0):

for this you can also try getOyoWindow.hide() inside your close button.onClick function. You can also try this in your else statement.
Hope this helps. Thanks.